# Replace with an apparition condition python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace

I have a file with a lot of parameters for a software, it looks like that :

```
CMaterial::m_HurkxPrefactor=6.14
CMaterial::m_HurkxFgamma=368800
CRegion::m_FrontDiff1:
In CDiffusion: ver_num=1
CDiffusion::m_Enable=0
CDiffusion::m_Type=0
CDiffusion::m_Profile=2
CDiffusion::m_Npeak=1e+020
CDiffusion::m_Depth=1.5e-005
CDiffusion::m_Xpeak=0
CRegion::m_FrontDiff2:
In CDiffusion: ver_num=1
CDiffusion::m_Enable=0
CDiffusion::m_Type=1
CDiffusion::m_Profile=0
CDiffusion::m_Npeak=9e+016
CDiffusion::m_Depth=0.018
CDiffusion::m_Xpeak=0
```

(with much more rows)

There is several region, the first "CDiffusion::m_Enable" control the properties of the first region, and the second apparition is for setting the second region.

I wish to take this text file and replace with my values.
For the moment I know how to change several parameter with this code, however it poorly manage the repetition of parameters in the file :

```
params = {'CDiffusion::m_Type': 3,
          'CDiffusion::m_Depth' : 0.018
          }
```

EDIT : missed this part of code

```
lab, val = [], []
    for k, v in params.items():
        lab.append(k)
        value.append(v)

s = f.read()
for num, val in enumerate(lab):
            s = re.sub('{0}=(.?)*'.format(val), '{1}={0}'.format(value[num], val), s)
```

but now I want for example to change "CDiffusion::m_Type" to 3 and the second "CDiffusion::m_Type" to 4.

Using this list of parameters and changing depending on the apparition of this last.

```
params = {'CDiffusion::m_Type': 3,
          'CDiffusion::m_Type': 4,
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT2:
@JoeIddon solution's is working, however i would like to maybe push it further:

```
lines = open('Test4.txt').read().strip().split('\n')

params = {
          'CDiffusion::m_Type':  ['3', 'False' ,'4'],
          'CDiffusion::m_Depth': ['5', '6', '5']
         }

with open('Test4.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for l in lines:
        try:
            k, v = l.split('=')
            if params[k] != 'False':
                nl = k + '=' + params[k].pop(0)
            else:
                nl = l
                params[k].pop(0)
        except (KeyError, IndexError, ValueError):
            nl = l
        fh.write(nl + '\n')
        print(nl)
fh.closed
```

I would like to not change the line if a certain value is in param, in this case 'false'. It doesn't seem to work though

Comment: The last dict is invalid because the same key cannot point to multiple values, the former will just get overwritten. Also, in your code example, where did `value` come from in the second string formatting?

Comment: Do all those different parameters need to be written in this particular order or it doesn't matter?

Comment: The order will matter, first apparition, => parameters for the first region, second apparition => parameters for the second region

Comment: @th0mash So you want to replace the first occurrence of m_type with 3, and the second occurrence of m_type with 4, right?

Comment: Since the order is important, you cannot simply search for the occurrence. I would suggest iterating through the input file, and checking each line for a match. If the line matches, substitute value and remove the used item from your dict of parameters.

Comment: abccd: value is an array of the parameter that I want to change
(I made a mistake since i didn't copy paste all my code)

Coffeehouse Coder: that's it

dr_agon: seems like a really good idea!

Comment: @th0mash If your comment contains some relevant code, please edit your question itself with it.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder done

Comment: "[apparition](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/apparition)"? That's a new one! (I didn't fix it 'cuz I've no idea what it's supposed to mean.)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Haha, so apparition is really appropriate for this situation in french, and i thought it was the same word.. maybe appearance ?

Comment: @th0mash If it's supposed to mean "an event of it appearing in the data", it's "appearance" indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary keys must be unique, so that last dictionary is invalid. What you really want is a dictionary where the values are lists. This will allow you to specify what the replacements should be in order. Also, as they are replacements in a file, they must be strings, not ints.

So, for example:

```
params = {
          'CDiffusion::m_Type':  ['3', '4'],
          'CDiffusion::m_Depth': ['5', '6']
         }
```

Now, to do this replacements in order, we cannot use `.replace` as that changes all occurrences; instead we must write our own method.

To do this, we could iterate over each line, split on the `'='`, and then retrieve the next replacement value from `params`. For that we can pop off the first item in the list (the first replacement) and use that when writing this new line (`nl` in the code).

The only last things we need to consider are the cases when the key (so the first half of the split) is not in our `params` dictionary and then also when it is in the dictionary, but for some reason, there is no replacement there to be made (i.e. the list is empty). These can be caught with `KeyError` and `IndexError`s respectively (so we will need a `try...except`). In addition, upon testing, I realised that not all the lines actually have `'='`s, so we also need to catch `ValueError`, for this case.

**update:**

You were very close with trying to add a case where the value isn't changed, but you had two things wrong.

First, since Python lists are allowed different data types in them (strings, ints, more lists, etc.), it will probably be easier to just literally use `False` instead of `'False'`, which will make the check easier.

Secondly, when you check if this case is one where need to skip (`False`), you are checking `params[k]`. This is wrong since `params[k]` will give us the list of replacements, not the *next* replacement. For the next replacement, you need to `pop(0)` as we have been doing.

So, the code (with `params` already defined and the update):

```
lines = open('f.txt').read().strip().split('\n')
with open('f.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for l in lines:
        try:
            k, v = l.split('=')
            r = params[k].pop(0)
            if r:
                nl = k + '=' + r
            else:
                nl = l
        except (KeyError, IndexError, ValueError):
            nl = l
        fh.write(nl + '\n')
```

---

Ok, I just tested it and it works; here's the file afterwards:

```
CMaterial::m_HurkxPrefactor=6.14
CMaterial::m_HurkxFgamma=368800
CRegion::m_FrontDiff1:
In CDiffusion: ver_num=1
CDiffusion::m_Enable=0
CDiffusion::m_Type=3
CDiffusion::m_Profile=2
CDiffusion::m_Npeak=1e+020
CDiffusion::m_Depth=5
CDiffusion::m_Xpeak=0
CRegion::m_FrontDiff2:
In CDiffusion: ver_num=1
CDiffusion::m_Enable=0
CDiffusion::m_Type=4
CDiffusion::m_Profile=0
CDiffusion::m_Npeak=9e+016
CDiffusion::m_Depth=6
CDiffusion::m_Xpeak=0
```

notice how the first `CDiffusion::m_Type` is now `3`, and the second one `4`, as well as how the first `CDiffusion::m_Depth` is now `5` and the second `6`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try after !

Comment: @th0mash I have now tested it and it's working, see my update

Comment: Thank you very much, It is working like a charm, however can you take a look at my second edit concerning value that i don't want to change!
Again, Thank you

Comment: @th0mash No problem, I have updated the answer again.